# How to prevent session loss after calling visit(uri)?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

Fairly new to capybara and cucumber (and testing in general) here.

I am doing some black box acceptance testing and I need to test a page that can only be reached by typing in the url.

That page requires authentication so when the page is reached through a call to visit() I am redirected to the login page.

The problem is after logging in the app does not redirect me back to that page but goes to the homepage instead so I can't just fill in the login form and move on.

I have tried logging in first and then performing a call to that page but it seems the session is cleared after any call to visit().

How can I keep the session after a call to visit, or solve this problem in any other way?

Ideally I would like to log in once and visit a bunch of pages only reachable by typing the uri, without having to log in again and again. Is that possible?

I am only using the chrome selenium driver but at some point will use a headless driver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the answer by @diabolist correctly states, `visit` doesn't reset any session (as long as your log in actions wait long enough for the log in to actually occur and the cookies to be set (expectation on a message stating you're logged in, or `have_current_path(root_path)` etc).  Rather the session gets reset between scenarios.

If, in one scenario, you are logging in and then finding that you're not logged in when you `visit` a page you expected to be logged in to then it's possible you're actually logging into the wrong domain. By default Capybara will visit a path on the host `127.0.0.1` - If that is where you're visiting but your app is redirecting to `localhost` (or `www.example.com`, etc) for logging in, then the session cookies will get set on the wrong domain and when you visit a page back on `127.0.0.1` you won't be logged in. If that is the case then you can either change `Capybara.server_host` or fix your app so it redirects to the correct place in the test environment.

Comment: It was the domain thing. Thanks! The app was redirecting on logging to localhost, but that was not the domain I was testing, so the "visit" call would call a different domain, on a session not authenticated

Answer (score 2):

```
Given I am registered
And  I am logged in
When I visit the test page
...
```

These can be implemented as
    Given "I am registered" do
      # do whatever it takes to be registered
    end

```
Given "I am logged in"
  #visit log in form and fill in id|password
end

When "I visit the test page" do
  visit test_page_url
end
```

Your idea that your session is cleared after each call to visit is wrong. Each scenario has its own session, and you can perform multiple visits in a scenario. However you have to make sure you login (and register) in one single scenario

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the scope of a session. My assumption was based on the behaviour I was experiencing but it was actually a domain issue due to a redirect on the app login.